# fillOval and correct use of paintComponent in actionListener

Tags: java, jframe, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I want to use `fillOval` outside of `paintComponent`; for example, `fillOval` in `actionListener`:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    int r = Math.max((maxx - minx) / 2, (maxy - miny) / 2);
    int nr = (int) Math.sqrt(2 * Math.pow(r, 2));
    int newx = minx - (nr - r);
    int newy = miny - (nr - r);

    iterator.add(new Object[] { newx, newy, nr, g2.getColor() });
    // remember
    paintComponent(g2);

}
```

I'm not sure whether `paintComponent(g2)` is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

> in paintComponent(g2) I'm not sure whether I correct or not.

It's never correct to call `paintComponent` directly. This method is responsibility of the Swing paint stack to call this method. Use `repaint` instead

```
repaint();
```